# Pass SQLConnection to Web service

Tags: java, web-services, database-connection, jax-ws

I have to pass a SQL Connection (java.sql.Connection) to a Web service. It seems impossible to serialize the SQLConnection object, so I was wondering if there is an easy way to share the same java.sql.Connection between two Web services, where one Web service call the other (synchronously called). I'm using JAX-WS.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this valid requirement at all? May be time to think design one more time?

Comment: We must use a Web service instead of a jar, because we want to make sure that if there's an error in our code, we don't have to recompile every apps that use that library. Multiple Web service do custom queries (using strings). They will call another web service which will use java genericity and hibernate to execute simple CRUD operations. Both needs the same connection, because we need both to be on the same transaction.